# How to use Google Apps with Google Sign-In (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, google-signin

When I try to login using Google Sign-In (2.4.0) on iOS 7, the application opens Web View, loads Google web-site and asks for a login and a password. It happens even if I have other applications from Google (like GMail) installed on my phone.

Is there a way to use Google applications for login if they are installed and use Web View otherwise?

I tried to set

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = false
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = false
```

But all I got is "No sign-in handlers installed"

`checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled` also returns `false`

Comment: Do you have the [Google Search App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-app-search-made-just/id284815942?mt=8) installed? I know that's one that should handle sign-in natively. (I'm not actually sure about Gmail)

Comment: No. It requires iOS 8. I have GMail and Google+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer from the team is, you're probably stuck using a WebView on iOS7. Due to some changes the team is making to improve the sign-in process on iOS9 (and up), you're going to start to see that iOS7 support is going to be a bit more basic than in the past.

It is a bit of a trade-off, but I think in the long run, it'll be worth it. Sorry I can't give you a better answer, tho.

Comment: I see, so it was not just the issue with the way I use the library, but the issue with the library itself, wasn't it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Google Sign-In iOS SDK Release Notes
**2016-05-18 -- v4.0.0**:

- **Removes allowsSignInWithBrowser and allowsSignInWithWebView
  properties from GIDSignIn**

This means that Google itself have removed these properties from their SignIn iOS SDK, we are not longer able to these properties.

Read more at [Google Sign-In iOS SDK Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release)